# Apache Module blocking access to FTP

Tags: permissions, centos, ftp, webserver, filezilla

EDIT: previous server admin changed all sites to use Apache Module. Now the sites only run on apache:apache

Problem is, now the client can't access their files in Filezilla, since originally the user permissions were ~domainuser~:psaserv.

This, of course, doesn't allow the CMS to run. Is there a clean way to fix this?

Is there a way to fix this, either by changing the server's settings through PLESK or some other workaround so both web and FTP are accessible?

Comment: What are the permissions set to for the files?

Comment: They are 644 for files

Answer (score 0):

What I do on my server is to make a group for each website that I host. This allows only the user(s) relevant to the website, plus the webserver itself, to access the files.

The www server (and in your case, the FTP server too) is part of this group. The user owning the website, in addition to anyone else who for some reason should have access, are also part of this group. This way, I can use the group-bit of the permission mask to control who can do what:

```
Owner - r/w
Group - r (and w if needed)
World - nothing
```

For most files, this means that the grup bit should be the same as the owner bit, i.e 660 and 640 for most of them.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. The previous dev lead changed something in Plesk so that all of the domains on the server run off of apache:apache, so unless I can change that, I'm locked in to that user and group, it seems.

Comment: @symlink no idea how to do that in plesk, but via the command prompt it is `chown -R username:groupname *`

Comment: the problem is that the web server needs apache:apache, while the FTP server needs ~domainusername~:psaserv

Comment: In that case, you need to change things around a bit. Make apache and domainusername part of the same group, and make sure that the group bit (the middle digit in the permission mask) is set to the same rights as the owner bit (the first one). Be sure to do this for all directories, including the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

With a little digging I was able to resolve the problem. The domain was running PHP as Apache module. When I switched it back to FastCGI, I was able to restore the user permissions to ~username~:psaserv. After that FTP and web services work fine.